# .NET 4.5 and WCF Request Compression

Tags: wcf, rest, compression, asp.net-4.5

We have a web application hosted on a third party hosting environment. The server application exposes some WCF RESTFUL services to our iPad applicaitons.

The WCF services are .svc-less and are registered in Glonbal.asax file. Sample:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.Add("service name", new ServiceRoute("url", 
    new WebServiceHostFactory(), routingServiceContract));
```

Since we need to transfer some massive data from our iPad apps to the server application, some of the requests are GZIP-compressed before being sent to the WCF service. And since the server app initially was built based on .NET 3.5 a piece of code like this has been in charge of decompressing the compressed requsts:

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"]))
  {                
    if (Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"].ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
     Request.Filter = new GZipStream(Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress);

    if (Request.Headers["Content-Encoding"].ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
      Request.Filter = new DeflateStream(Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress);
  }
}
```

This was working until our hosting provider installed .NET 4.5 on their server. Then the compressed JSON requests began to fail (we get http 400 or sometimes 500 errors). After so much investigation it turned out that the code and web.config file are all OK because the WCF service work perfectly on a server that does not have .NET 4.5 installed.

I even commented the above code and published to the same sever but it did not work again.  I had thought the request was getting decoded twice!.

Now I am wondering how can I take advantage of WCF 4.5 built-in compression feature and get this web site working? I prefer to get rid of the custom c# code and just use WCF 4.5 compression feature.

p.s. the web service is running in ASP.NET Compatibility mode.

p.p.s. the web service works perfectly if we do not compress the http request.

Comment: A few questions : (1) Is this a 3.5 application or a 4.0 application. A 3.5 application may not be impacted by 4.5 install as 4.5 is an update to 4.0 run time. (2) Do you see that calls are successful if you comment your compression code and send uncompressed requests? (3) Could you post your web.config and a little repro some where for us to have a look? I am interested in seeing how the binding settings looks like.

Comment: 1- This is a .NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application.  2- No if we comment the compression code it won't help. If we keep the compression code and built the site then copy the same pre-compiled web site to a server that has .NET 4.0 (not 4.5) it works.   3- I will try to post the web.config file here. I need to ask the big boss for permission :)

Comment: @Praburaj - To clarify, sending _uncompressed_ requests with the compression code disabled (or enabled for that matter) works as expected.

Comment: @Praburaj I've created a [stackoverflow chat "room"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20540/net-4-5-and-wcf-request-compression-13619253) to avoid extended comments. I'll post links to the config and any other relevant code in there.

Comment: Perhaps you should use this if its a WCF-WCF communication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I went over your configuration file & Application_BeginRequest method. I replicated your config file on my machine with .net 4.0 and verified that it worked fine. I could also see that the same settings fail on a machine with .net 4.5. Based on my observation your issue is not related to compression / decompression code that you have in Application_BeginRequest. But you are running into the same issue that I have described in this [post][1]

[1]: [WCF - Conflicting endpoints after .Net 4.5 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643113/wcf-conflicting-endpoints-after-net-4-5-installation) "Post". In this post I have also posted the work around for this issue. Work around is to define the REST endpoint explicitly. On following the same work around I could see your project started working. Precisely all I had to do to get your project working is add these two lines in the config and explicitly configure the service endpoint.

```
    <services>
      <service name="<YourNamespace>.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="<YourNamespace>.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Can you check if this solves your problem?

Comment: It was my (recent) understanding that the `<service />` and `<endpoint />` elements were ignored when you use `ServiceRoute`. Is that not the case?

Comment: Adding explicit service endpoints causes the service method ("[endpointadddress]/method") to 404. However, removing *all system.serviceModel config* except serviceHostingEnvironment still results in the non-compressed request working as expected (no doubt due to the ServiceRoute). Compressed requests, however, still fail with a 400, even though the BeginRequest code is executed for that request.

Comment: @RichardSzalay, Could you send me an email to netfx45compat at microsoft.com. Also I feel I might be missing some information. It would be nice if you have a quick small repro project.