# .Net Framework 4.5 stopped working WCF Restful application in 4.0

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

We have Application in WCF-Rest service with .Net framework 4.0, after installing .net framework 4.5 application stopped functioning, exception gets logged in Application Event Viewer.
If we uninstall .Net Framework 4.5, application works as expected. Anyone knows what is the issue with .Net 4.5 for WCF Rest in 4.0?

We tried 
[WCF - Conflicting endpoints after .Net 4.5 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643113/wcf-conflicting-endpoints-after-net-4-5-installation) but didn't help to resolve the issue.

### Event Viewer Application Log

WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/13495405
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): There was no channel actively listening at 'http://XYS/ABC/EmployeeService/GetEmployee?ID="11"'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://XYS/ABC/EmployeeService/GetEmployee?ID="11"'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 1600

Comment: Sorry to hear that you are running into an issue. I work in Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility team. I would like to help. Could you email me with small project that reproduces the issue at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? Sincerely, Varun (Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility Team)

Comment: Could you provide us code that reproduces the issue at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com.

Comment: Thanks varun as of now we have removed .net 4.5

Comment: I am getting this exact same problem. Has there been any ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: What I understand that Microsoft has decided to stop webhttpbinding with WCF instead use WebAPI from ASP.Net MVC4. But this is not good, frameworks should be backward compatible, if my understanding is correct then every one has to rewrite the application on new framework, which will include cost + time.